# how to install yowsup in windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, yowsup

I installed yowsup by using "pip" command

> pip install yowsup2
>   Collecting yowsup2
>     Downloading yowsup2-2.5.7.tar.gz (112kB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 520kB/s
>   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\users\radia\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from yowsup2)`enter code here`
>   Requirement already satisfied: argparse in c:\users\radia\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from yowsup2)

but when i am trying to run below command;:-
yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 49XXXXXXXX --cc 49 --mcc 123 --mnc 456 --env android
 I'm getting below error,

C:\Users\radia>yowsup-cli registration
'yowsup-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Put the directory where yowsup-cli is installed into %PATH%, or specify the full hierarchic filename.

Answer (score 0):

The path to yowsup-cli isn't automatically included in your %PATH%, so you have to include it yourself, or just run the command in the directory where the yowsup-cli file is located